# How to add a self-signed certificate as an exception in Chrome?

Tags: ssl-certificate, https, google-chrome

I have a number of network devices that I access over HTTPS. However, they are self-signed certificates, so Chrome displays a warning page.

[image]

In earlier versions of chrome, I seem to remember an "add exception" button on this screen, or on the certificate's information window (if you clicked the HTTPS in the address bar). However, that has long since disappeared.

How can I add an exception for specific self-signed certificates in Chrome 28?

Comment: Are you trying to get this done on multiple workstations or just yours?

Comment: Just a single workstation.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7580508/getting-chrome-to-accept-self-signed-localhost-certificate

Answer (score 23, accepted):

1. Export the certificate from Chrome.

   - To view the certificate click Inspect on the page and go the the Tab
     Security: [image]
   - Now click on View Certificate and export the certificate by clicking
     on Copy to file... In the wizard choose Base 64 encoded .Cer. Now
     save the certificate on your Desktop.
     [image]
2. Import the certificate into your trusted root certification
   authority store.

   - Go to Start | and run the command `certmgr.msc`.
   - Expand the tree to get to Trusted Root Certification Authorities |
     Certificates. Go to All Tasks, choose Import and import the
     certificate in question.

**OR**

- In chrome settings search for Manage  certificates. Click on it and
  import the certificate under Trusted Root certificate Authorities.

  [image]

Comment: Thanks @Forceflow -- that's a shortcut I'll use myself in the future.

Comment: Well, I imported the cert successfully, but when I refreshed the HTTPS page, it still showed the certificate warning. When I looked in the certificate manager, I couldn't find the imported certificate anywhere.

Comment: You still need to make sure the name matches the website address you are connecting to. You could edit your /etc/hosts file as one solution.

Comment: I am connecting via IP, not a domain or host name.

Comment: I should say that the CN needs to match--can be an IP address or a hostname.

Comment: Ah, the CN was set to something generic. After setting it to the IP address, the warning no longer appeared.

Comment: Doesn't work anymore...

Comment: New Chrome: Open page "Inspector" - Pick 'Security' tab - pick 'View certificate' - Follow answer from there.

Comment: Doesn't work for Windows if the issuer does not exist.

Answer (score 13):

**For Mac OS X:**

Click on the Certificate icon in the address bar. Click on "Certificate Information", then drag and drop the certificate image to your desktop or any other folder.

Double click the cer file you've just saved, it will open in the Keychain Access.

Choose a keychain to store it (I think this step is specific to Yosemite), for example "login", and finally click "always trust".

If you're not being asked where to save it or if you should trust it, locate the newly added certificate (it should be at the top of your list), right click it, choose "get info" and then choose "Always trrust" in the Trust tab, under "When using this certificate".

**UPDATE 25/2/2017**

Chrome doesn't show the certificate options next to the URL, you now have to open the developer tools (Option + Command + i) and go to the "Security" tab. You can then click "View Certificate" and follow the above instructions from the drag and drop and onwards.

You can also enable the more direct certificate link again by following these instructions:
[How to view SSL Certificate details on Chrome?](https://superuser.com/questions/1160502/how-to-view-ssl-certificate-details-on-chrome)

Comment: This procedure does not work for my Synology NAS. I can confirm, that the certificat is imported into KeyChain. But I still get the same error message from Chrome.

Comment: I'm experiencing similar issues, as BetaRide, but I think this is down to the hostname of the cert, which is different to the name the cert was created with

Comment: When I put the certificate in my "login" chain, it didn't make any difference.  I had to put it in the chain for my username and changed the "Use Custom Settings" trust level to "Always Trust", which changed all of the other options to that setting, not just the one for "X.509 Basic Policy".

Comment: Thanks for your comment @L S, hopefully it will help other users with the same issue ;-)

Comment: Actually, you can leave it in the login keychain, right click it, choose "get info" and then choose "Always trrust" in the Trust tab, under "When using this certificate"

Answer (score 1):

For OS X, to do it from the command line:

```
sudo security add-trusted-cert -p ssl -d -r trustRoot -k ~/Library/Keychains/login.keychain selfsigned.crt
```

If you don't have a .crt file (`selfsigned.crt` in this command) already to reference, view the cert in Chrome and drag it to your desktop.