# How to view SSL Certificate details on Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

Before somewhere around Chrome 55, I could look at the details of a certificate a website is using by clicking on the Green lock icon. Now that functionality seems to be gone; see picture below.

How can I bring this back? I know I can go into Developer Console -> Security but it's tad bit inconvenient.

[image]

Comment: Functionality still exists, verified on multiple Pcs

Comment: @Ramhound Mine looks like this: http://imgur.com/a/AE7IC

Comment: I spent some time myself looking around in the Chrome UI and not finding any way to view the actual certificate without going to the Security tab in devtools. So I think the answer is, that’s now the only way—there is no longer any way from lock icon or other normal menus to get to “View certificate” and the protocol/key-exchange/cipher details.

Comment: This still works for me: `Lock Icon > Details > View Certificate` (Windows 7, Chrome 55).  I suppose this is an anomaly specific to the macOS version of Google Chrome.

Comment: @mockturtl I am not on Chrome 57. I've had it for several versions now, and I'm not exactly sure when they changed the behaviour on OSX.

Comment: seeing this now: worst decision ever by google. i can not think of one valid reason why this should be moved somewhere else.
mindblowingly stupid.

Comment: Boooo! What was Google thinking to hide important info from the average user. We should make this easier to find not harder!!!

Comment: Please vote (star) for the bug at https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=663971

Comment: Apparently a future version will have put this back into page info: https://textslashplain.com/2017/05/02/inspecting-certificates-in-chrome/

Comment: @legoscia https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=663971 confirms this: `Re #100: The certificate link will be available by default in a future release.`

Comment: It's still not available in `Version 61.0.3163.100 (Official Build) (64-bit)`.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

As of Chrome 60 it is possible to return certificate details under "lock" menu. This option has to be enabled manually by accessing `chrome://flags/#show-cert-link`.

When you enable it and restart the Chrome, option to view certificate will be visible when you click on lock icon.

[image: Menu with Certificate option]

Comment: This feature seems not to be available on v.65 on Mac OS. Following chrome://flags/#show-cert-link directly lists no results. Likewise, when searching for show-cert-link, no results are listed.

Comment: I cannot say for Mac OS with full certainity but on Mint/Ubuntu and Windows, his behavior now seems to be default and thus this flag is no longer necessary.

Comment: I could've sworn I didn't have an option to display the certificate info. Thanks, man!

Comment: How about for websites that are not trusted?

Answer (score 115):

You can now find this information in Developer Tools. `Three Dots Menu > More Tools > Developer Tools`, then click the "Security" tab and you'll get a "Security Overview" with a "View certificate" button.

Comment: This is also the only way now, and has been for quite some time. The "Details" link also lead(s) there.

Comment: Starting with Chrome 56 this is the only method

Comment: This is actually what the OP already mentioned.

Comment: F12 for quick open developer tool

Comment: Doesn't work on a Mac.

Comment: @AStudentataUniversity It's ⌘⌥I

Comment: Starting with Chrome 60 you can add back the original functionality: https://www.flexibledeveloper.com/2017/08/easily-view-certificates-google-chrome-60/

Answer (score 25):

From that menu, you have to follow below path:

> Click on "Customize and control Google Chrome" >> More tools >>
>   Developer tools >> Security >> View Certificate.

Check this screen-shot:

[image]

Or...

```
Simply press F12 >> Security >> View Certificate.
```

For Mac Users:

```
⌘ + Option + i
```

Comment: When I click Learn More, Chrome simply takes me to [this page](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95617?visit_id=1-636190912769265600-3289433141&p=ui_security_indicator&rd=1).

Comment: This is for the older versions of Google Chrome like v54. Version 56 seems to have changed it.

Answer (score 10):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> brings up Security Overview in Chrome 56.

Comment: Not entirely correct - it brings up the Developer Tools and shows the last used tab.

Comment: Doesn't work on a mac.

Comment: Does anything work on a Mac?

Answer (score 5):

Not sure why this hasn't been mentioned yet, but you can hit F12 to bring up the developer window, and then switch to the 'Security' tab to view the certificates. May be easier than Ctrl + Shift + I.

Answer (score 1):

I have Chromium 55 on one OS and Chromium 56 on another, so can see the difference.  An unwelcome change, but the 'developer tools' tab remembers settings, so all I have to do to check the cert in Chromium 56 is click F12, and then 'View Certificate,' as before.

Answer (score -4):

You can click on the icon to the left of the URL, which is the letter 'i' in a circle. The Details link has an option to view the SSL certificate.

Comment: As mentioned above, this is what I see when I click on it: imgur.com/a/AE7IC