# How to view SSL Certificate details on Chrome when Developer Tools are disabled?

Tags: google-chrome, security, certificate, tls

Before somewhere around Chrome 55, I could look at the details of a certificate a website is using by clicking on the Green lock icon:

[image]

Now that functionality seems to be gone; see picture below:

[image]

How can I bring this back? I know I can go into Developer Console -> Security [but it's a](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/66239/how-to-prevent-installation-of-google-chrome-extensions) tad impossible:

[image]

I want to know that i'm seeing the correct certificate (e.g. issuing authority, SHA-1 fingerprint); and that someone isn't attempting to intercept my communications.

## Bonus Reading

- [How to view SSL Certificate details on Chrome?](https://superuser.com/questions/1160502/how-to-view-ssl-certificate-details-on-chrome)
- [How Do You View SSL Certificate Details in Google Chrome?](https://www.howtogeek.com/292076/how-do-you-view-ssl-certificate-details-in-google-chrome/)
- [Option to view SSL certificate details removed?](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/dDTJYdWTUxM;context-place=topicsearchin/chrome/category$3Areport-a-problem-and-get-troubleshooting-help%7Csort:relevance%7Cspell:false)

### How to do it in Edge

It is possible to view a site's TLS certificate in Microsoft Edge, although it's somewhat tedious:

- Click the <kbd>...</kbd> option

  [image]
- Click **Open with Internet Explorer**

  [image]
- Click the  in the address bar, and select **View Certificates**

  [image]
- And now you have the details of TLS certificate

  [image]

Tedious; although one step shorter than viewing it in Chrome (when DevTools are available).

Answer (score 5):

As of Chrome 60 it is possible to return certificate details under "lock" menu. This option has to be enabled manually by accessing chrome://flags/#show-cert-link.

When you enable it and restart the Chrome, option to view certificate will be visible when you click on lock icon.

Comment: Why does this answer look so [familiar](https://superuser.com/questions/1160502/how-to-view-ssl-certificate-details-on-chrome/1244513#1244513)?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know the Developer Tools are the only way of showing it without installing a extension from the Chrome Web Store, but if a extension is okay you could use "CertViewer" ("https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/certviewer/dcfpfgpnkmklbdnicbooifodgdekdgie").

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a way to view the certificate faster in Chrome however, you could bookmark an SSL Checker website like this one:

https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html

Like I said, there could be a better way but this is all I know of and is what I use to check important websites before I use them. I hope this helped :)